# UICollectionViewCell issues calling method

Tags: ios, crash, uicollectionviewcell

I'm simply trying to call a method with a custom UICollectionViewCell and it's crashing with SIGABRT

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([_leaderboardDictionary count] > 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        return [self insertLeaderBoardCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        return [self insertDetailGraphicCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}

-(CampaignDetailGraphic2Cell *)insertDetailGraphicCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CampaignDetailGraphic2Cell *cell = (CampaignDetailGraphic2Cell *)[_topCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"detailWebCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        if(is3_5Inches)
        {
            cell = [[CampaignDetailGraphic2Cell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 172)];
        }
        else
        if(is4Inches)
        {
            cell = [[CampaignDetailGraphic2Cell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 220)];
        }
        else
        if(isIphone6)
        {
            cell = [[CampaignDetailGraphic2Cell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 355, 290)];
        }
        else
        if(isIphone6Plus)
        {
            cell = [[CampaignDetailGraphic2Cell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 394, 356)];
        }
    }

    [cell setupCell];
```

...

}

This method exists within my CampaignDetailGraphic2Cell class.

Any idea how I can call methods and set properties of a cell ... ?

Comment: Where did you make this cell? Code, storyboard, xib?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create UICollectionViewCells with alloc init.  You need to register a class or nib file when you set up the collection and then dequeue the cell.  Once you do that you can call the methods on your cell.

ie

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[CampaignDetailGraphic2Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CampaignCell"];
```

then

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CampaignDetailGraphic2Cell* cell = (CampaignDetailGraphic2Cell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CampaignCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ...
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I've gone ahead and removed the alloc calls ... The cells now stretch to the size of the collection view. Now though, where in my controller do I set the cell's properties (e.g. title text, background colour, etc.) ... ? Thanks!

Comment: You can set properties in the `-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Comment: Great I can now ... but the actual issue (not allowing me to set the properties) was that the .xib file didn't have the correct class set ... *sigh* ... it was set to UITableViewCell ... Thanks for your help!!!